Why does CutomView change its size in MotionLayout when width is fixed?
I use MotionLayout to animate the selected gift card. The card itself is a CustomView with a TickerView and two TextViews inside.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/openGiftContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_new_loyalty_rewarding_corners_card"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/grid_3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ru.secret.secret.customviews.v3.ticker.TickerView
        android:id="@+id/ivIconTicker"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_9"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_9"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/H0.TxtIconAlwaysBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_3_5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/grid_2"
        tools:text="word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        style="@style/Body1.Regular.TxtIconNeutrals2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_2_5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/grid_3_5"
        tools:text="word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

Text of different lengths may come from the backend for the TextView, but we expect it to be no more than two lines. CustomView width in MotionScene and fragment Layout set to `match_parrent
The problem is that the width is set to match_parent everywhere, but I'm not sure that this is the case during view rotation (rotationY). Words from the second line of both TextViews can go to the first line during animation. I don’t know how to fix this except by fixing the width and height of the Layout inside the CustomView. Are there better ways?
MotionScene
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    motion:defaultDuration="10000">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/transitionOpenGiftToCongrats"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/endGiftScaleToCenter"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/startGiftScaleToCenter">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            ...
            <!--CongratsOpenGiftView-->
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="0"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="49"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="1"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="1"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView" />
            ...
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/startGiftScaleToCenter">
        ...
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:rotationY="180"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/endGiftScaleToCenter">
        ...
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:rotationY="360"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
</MotionScene>

Fragment layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootML"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_choice_rewarding_liner_gradient"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/open_gift_to_congrats_scene">
    
    ...

    <ru.broker.feature.loyalty.impl.view.new_views.CongratsOpenGiftView
        android:id="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>


You can set constraints in your MotionLayout to maintain the width of the CustomView.
<Constraint         android:id="@+id/congratsOpenGiftView"         android:layout_width="0dp" <!-- Change here -->

Did not help. I set 0dp on all hierarchies. It seems to me that the problem is that the card goes off the screen during rotation.

Address the width inconsistency issue by setting the fixed widths for your textViews inside your customView.
   <!-- CongratsOpenGiftView.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ru.secret.secret.customviews.v3.ticker.TickerView
        android:id="@+id/ivIconTicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/H0.TxtIconAlwaysBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_3_5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/grid_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivIconTicker"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        style="@style/Body1.Regular.TxtIconNeutrals2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_2_5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/grid_3_5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Also didn't help... I think the reason is cacd motion and rotation. CustomView resizes width despite limitations
